# Static file referenced by handler not found when Crud to ASP.NET Core

Tags: angular, crud

I learn Angular and I have this Angular 8 client app on Google app engine.
I get this error in the log

> Static file referenced by handler not found:
>   dist/api/BooksXml/title/ruby

The `api/BooksXml` is my Crud rout in the Angular service like this:

```
private BookItemsUrl = 'api/BooksXml';  // URL to web api
```

The `/title` is the Crud qualifier like this

```
  /** GET book by title from server. */
  getBookByTitle(title: string): Observable<BookItem[]> {
    const url = `${this.BookItemsUrl}/title/${title}`;
    return this.http.get<BookItem[]>(url);
  }
```

The `/ruby` is the name of the book I search for.

Backend is ASP.NET Core. This all works on localhost but at App engine I get this error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular thinks your `api/BooksXml/title/ruby` is a static file. There is 2 solutions to call your back-end: use a proxy or change your `BookItemsUrl` with the backend URL.

**Change the `BookItemsUrl` URL**
This solution may not work if you don't enable CORS.

```
private BookItemsUrl = 'http://<server_name>:<port_number>/api/BooksXml'
```

OR

**Use a proxy**
Check the [Angular documentation](https://angular.io/guide/build#proxying-to-a-backend-server) if you don't know about proxy.

1. Create a file `src/proxy.config.json`:

```
{
  "/api": {
    "target": "http://<server_name>:<port_number>",
    "secure": false
  }
}
```

2. In the `angular.json` add the `proxyConfig` option:

```
...
"architect": {
  "serve": {
    "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
    "options": {
      "browserTarget": "your-application-name:build",
      "proxyConfig": "src/proxy.conf.json"
    },
...
```

> Note that if you edit the proxy configuration file, you must relaunch
>   the ng serve process to make your changes effective.

Comment: Thanks nothing of this works I think the problem is the backend, the NET.ASP Core Controller Crud is not listening i think

Comment: Test the backend (with Postman for example) to check if it is returning the values.

Comment: I know what was wrong, first I used this [Http://unique-yew-244216.appspot.com]() as the  BookItemsUrl  , then I notice there´s also this [Http://v0-dot-unique-yew-244216.appspot.com](), I learn this and why is there two different adresses. I now see incoming event with the exception that backend cant find books.xml

Comment: The books.xml is in the root folder, should it be in the www maybe

Comment: yea setting private BookItemsUrl did the trick. Exception say "Could not find file '/app/books.xml'.",